# How to develop an ipad app that only supports english?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, translate

I am trying to develop an app on ipad.
But when I use geocoding and google api, I see other language place name(even though the place is in US).
It seems like it's translating english. 
Is there any way to have only english on my app?
Thank you

Comment: This question could be more related to google api rather than iOS and iPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Its's this

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[defaults synchronize];
```